# Animation-fill-forwards not working with hover selector

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

I wanted to have an image fade permanently until the user refreshes the page, and I was able to do so with animation-fill forwards. However, I would like this animation to initiate only when you hover over it.

I am able to make an image fade with hover independently, but it resets after the user moves their cursor from the element. In short, I am unable to make the transition and the hover effect work in conjunction.

Here is the HTML

```
    <div class="hill">
    <img id="hill" src="https://i.postimg.cc/rw48gd3R/hillary.png">
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
body {
  height:1000px;
}

#hill {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 100vh; 
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  0%   { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fade {
  0%   { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-o-keyframes fade {
  0%   { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes fade {
  0%   { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

#hill {
  -webkit-animation: fade 5s;
  -moz-animation:    fade 5s;
  -o-animation:      fade 5s;
  animation:         fade 5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

This is the codepen to my project: https://codepen.io/narutofan389/collab/LYpxqmY

Much obliged for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:hover state only applies when it is hovered, so it will not persist. I would recommend toggling a class on mouseenter via javascript. I've attached a fiddle to accomplish what you're intending. Let me know if you need any clarity. :)

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var img = document.getElementById("hill");
  
  img.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() { img.classList.add("hide")});
});
```

```css
body {
  height:1000px;
}

#hill {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  0%   { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fade {
  0%   { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-o-keyframes fade {
  0%   { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes fade {
  0%   { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}

#hill.hide {
  -webkit-animation: fade 5s;
  -moz-animation:    fade 5s;
  -o-animation:      fade 5s;
  animation:         fade 5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="hill">
    <img id="hill" src="https://i.postimg.cc/rw48gd3R/hillary.png">
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much Joel, You're a life saver 

Comment: Would you mind marking this question 'answered' so it can help people in the future? Thanks, and glad to be of help!

Answer (score 0):

You can consider `animation-play-state` and have the animation defined on the element initially but the duration need to be short because it won't work if the user rapidly move the mouse

```css
#hill {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  animation: fade 0.5s paused forwards;
}


#hill:hover {
  animation-play-state:running;
}

@keyframes fade {
  0%   { opacity: 1; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<img id="hill" src="https://i.postimg.cc/rw48gd3R/hillary.png">
```